# What tense is appropriate for answering "What do they do?"

Tags: grammar

How should I answer to "What do they do?"

1. They are teaching.
2. They teach.

Answer (score -1):

1. They are teaching: If someone is teaching right now.
2. They teach: If someone is a teacher.

I guess it is no. 2. Probably someone wants to know what they do for a living.

Comment: The first would the reply to "What are they doing?"